# Bug on topbar showing pending suggested edits while I am done with edits for today

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, top-bar

I was reviewing some suggested edits and some other posts on SO today.

Aftera short while I have exhausted by contigent of reviews for the suggested edits queue. As I still wanted to do some other reviews, I stumbled upon a minor bug.

Despite not being allowed to do any reviews, I got the topbar indicating that there is pending reviews. I took a screenshot (and edited it to decrease the size by removing all the other review queues from the image).

[image: topbar indicating pending reviews for suggested edits]

This did not happen all the time, but could be reproduced by using the review link in the topbar now and then.

Comment: That's a question from 2011. I don't think it need be relevant to what is currently new (I've not seen it before today) in the new topbar.

Comment: Same here, I've never seen that notification until today.

Comment: I cannot say this as I only have 2k rep for a few days but it surprised me enough to search and later post this bug report. On the other hand the other post has a status-declined tag